# Contour plot from a 3D array in Python

Tags: matplotlib, contourf

I have a [128x128x128] array. From this I need to plot 1 single plane, i.e., the central plane along the z-axis, so I will have to use the array in the form A[:,:,64].

Do you know which commands should I type in order to get this contour plot?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array like this one:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.random.rand(128, 128, 128)

A.shape
#Output:
(128, 128, 128)
```

Then you take out one plane by index:

```py
A[:, :, 64].shape
#Output:
(128, 128)
```

When plotting with `plt.contourf()`, [X, Y] arguments are optional, so if you want to plot just one array along Z-axis, just pass the array you selected as an argument:

```py
plt.contourf(ndarray[:, :, 64])
plt.show()
```

And you get this as an output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It was what I needed to take the plot.